# Which of this two A/B test set-up is better?

Tags: experiment-design, ranking, random-allocation

My goal is to conduct an A/B test to compare if our new customer ranking algorithm is better than the old one in terms of conversion rate (for our call center). I have two set-up scenarios in mind but struggling to figure out which one is better.

**Set-up 1:**

Every time a customer comes in, randomly put the customer into either **pool A** or **pool B** (50/50). Then when a contact center representative tries to claim a customer, randomly assign the representative to claim either from pool A or pool B (50/50). If the representative is assigned to pool A customers, then use the new ranking algorithm to pick the top 1 customer in pool A otherwise use the old ranking algorithm to pick the top 1 in pool B.

**Set-up 2:**

Put all customers in one pool. Every time a contact center representative tries to claim a customer, randomly decide whether to use the new ranking algorithm or the old one (50/50). Then pick the top 1 customer based on the ranking algorithm selected.

I have a feeling that set-up 1 is a cleaner way but I cannot find a scenario demonstrating that set-up 2 is flawed...

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing. I think you are just confusing yourself by calling each pool of customers A and B when really you're AB testing the new ranking algorithm vs the old. As long as each person in your sample is randomly assigned to either A or B and the split is even then it doesn't matter. In this case set-up 2 would actually be better as you aren't wasting a step into separating into two arbitrary groups.